# Localisation_setting.bundle

Tags: iphone, localization, settings.bundle

Just wanted to ask, how to localize Xibs via settings.bundle? Actually, I need to make my Xib arabic through settings.bundle. I have searched a lot for this. Please give me proper suggestions otherwise i need to recode my application and remove all contents of Xibs and do it via coding which would take a lot of time.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey just paste this following code in your main.m file

```
       NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        NSString *strLang=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"PSMultiValueSpecifier"];
       NSLog(@"Hi%@",strLang);
    //    
        if ([strLang isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", @"ar",  nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        }
        else if([strLang isEqualToString:@"1"])
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ar", @"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
        }

  int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed this [post](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/17/localizing-iphone-app-settings-strings.html) to get apps localised.

Answer (score 0):

you can localize you nib file by keeping you xib file in specific language folder, e.g. 
`en.lproj/View1.xb` is the english version 
and 
`ar.lproj/View.xib` is the arabic version
for more detailed instructions [see this](http://iphoneobjectivec.blogspot.com/2010/12/internationalise-and-localization-in.html)

**UPDATE:**
for that you simply create

- View-en.xib
- View-ar.xib

and then based on your custom settings

```
NSString *xibName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"View-%@", @"en"];    
id localVC = [[LocalViewController alloc] initWithNibName:xibName bundle:nil];
```

Comment: Hey i was actually talking about Localization via settings.The thing which u r specifying is Localization done when we change the Lannguage in the iphone. But i am looking for Localization via settings bundle See Trackers app.

Answer (score 0):

hit 'get info' by right clicking the xib you wish to localize... and within the general screen you can see the 'Make File Localizable' button on there.

Answer (score 0):

@aamritrao if you make two separate XIB files, one for each language, you shouldn't give them different names as that just complicates things unnecessarily. Just name them the same but put them in different localized project folders.

So:

en.lproj/View1.XIB

and

ar.lproj/View1.XIB

Then when your app needs View1.XIB it will always use the appropriate one for the language the user has set in their device settings.

Sorry if this is not what you are looking for. Not sure what you mean by 'Localization via settings bundle'... could you explain more?

Comment: Hi, Localization via settings bundle means we can see our application in settings bundle and change the language from there. Please See Trackers app.

Comment: Sounds like they are handling all the localization themselves rather than having the device and OS handle it because I don't think it is possible to programmatically change the language settings of the device from within your app. To do this you need to learn how to create a settings bundle (lots of info in the Apple docs and on the web) and then you would need to have logic based on the settings that would use different xibs, plists etc to serve the content in your app.